# Swift - dynamically initialise ResearchKit classes based on a server response

Tags: ios, swift, dynamic, researchkit

ResearchKit has `ORKOrderedTask` a class to add steps like Instruction, Survey, Activity to it. Through class mapping I determine the given response from server comes under which step. And my mapping is as follows

```
let classMapping = [
"ORKInstructionStep": ORKInstructionStep.self,
"ORKQuestionStep": ORKQuestionStep.self,
"ORKFormStep": ORKFormStep.self,
"ORKFormItem": ORKFormItem.self
]
```

If I add a question step to `ORKOrderedTask`. And the question step structure to store data from server is as follows

```
struct QuestionGroup {
let identifier, title, text : String
let answerFormat: ORKAnswerFormat
init(identifier: String, title: String, text: String, answerFormat: ORKAnswerFormat) {
    self.identifier   = identifier
    self.title = title
    self.text  = text
    self.answerFormat = ORKAnswerFormat()
}
}
```

And I store the date to the question group structure from server as follows

```
LIbraryAPI.sharedInstance.questionList.append(QuestionGroup(identifier: row["objectId"]!.string!, 
title: row["title"]!.string!, text: row["text"]!.string!, answerFormat: ORKBooleanAnswerFormat()))
```

In the above code the **answerFormat** is hard coded as of now, but can be of any of the answer format in this following enum

```
enum AnswerFormat: Int {
case ORKScaleAnswerFormat = 0,
ORKContinuousScaleAnswerFormat,
ORKValuePickerAnswerFormat,
ORKImageChoiceAnswerFormat,
ORKTextChoiceAnswerFormat,
`ORKBooleanAnswerFormat`,
ORKNumericAnswerFormat,
ORKTimeOfDayAnswerFormat,
ORKDateAnswerFormat,
ORKTextAnswerFormat,
ORKTimeIntervalAnswerFormat
   }
```

For each answer format there will be different argument to pass. Following is the final code where I add the question step to **ORKOrderedTask**.

```
  if let questionStep  = classMapping["ORKQuestionStep"] as? ORKQuestionStep {
    let tempStep = questionStep.dynamicType
    let group = LIbraryAPI.sharedInstance.questionList
    for eachGroup in group {
        let finalQuestionStep = tempStep(identifier: eachGroup.identifier, title: eachGroup.title, answer: eachGroup.answerFormat)
        steps += [finalQuestionStep]
    }
}
```

So my problem is the server passes me different kind of answer format for each question.  How do I dynamically create the instance of each answer format that comes under `AnswerFormat` enum? Because `ORKBooleanAnswerFormat` does not have any arguments, on the other hand `ORKTextChoiceAnswerFormat` can have an array of strings as an argument and Date answer format must be supplied with max and min date so on and so forth.

So how do I manage all these and bring under one single class or function to make it reusable for all the answer format classes?

Comment: Have a look at [Josh Smith's *ObjectFactory*](http://ijoshsmith.com/2014/06/05/instantiating-classes-by-name-in-swift/), it might be helpful to your needs.